# Having trouble testing php to send email verification in xampp

Tags: codeigniter, email, xampp

I have to write a log in, registration, and restricted members functionality for a site, i everything works but i cant test sending the verification email, but need too. see if it sends and test the verification link in the email.

i am running an Acer Aspire 5920,

Ubuntu 12.04,

Xampp 1.8.1,

Codeigniter 2.1.3

Answer (score -1):

In answer to my own question i needed to pass infomation to configure xampp to send the email:

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'gmail.login@googlemail.com',
'smtp_pass' => 'your_password',
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('gmail.login@googlemail.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('recipient@destination.tld');

$this->email->subject(' CodeIgniter Rocks Socks ');
$this->email->message('Hello World');


if (!$this->email->send()){
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}else{
    echo 'Your e-mail has been sent!'; 
}
```